# angular + ui-router: $stateChangeSuccess triggered on state b but not on a.b

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

ui-router 0.2.11 / AngularJS 1.3.0

I struggle to understand why my $stateChangeSuccess event handler in BarCtrl is not triggered on #/foo/bar. It is triggered on #/bar.

```
#/foo/bar -> Console: foo
#/bar -> Console: bar
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that on #/foo/bar first FooCtrl's handler is triggered and then BarCtrl's:

```
foo
bar
```

My code:

```
var app = angular.module('foobar', ['restangular', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router'])
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('root', {
    url: "/",
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
  })
  .state('foo', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/foo",
    controller: 'FooCtrl',
  })
  .state('foo.bar', {
    url: "/bar",
    controller: 'BarCtrl',
  })
  .state('bar', {
    url: "/bar",
    controller: 'BarCtrl',
  });
})

app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log("foo");
  });
});

app.controller('BarCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log('bar')
  });
});
```

Comment: Ensure that `BarCtrl` is invoked when `#/foo/bar`

Comment: @Alexei: could you explain a bit more? I was thinking all controllers in the foo.bar chain would get invoked, the docs say: 'when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.'

Comment: Could you prepare a fiddle? I just checked that locally and all works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While preparing a fiddle I came across my mistakes. I was thinking abstract views would not need a template since they cannot be accessed and assuming the template of foo's parent state would take over, which is not the case.

To achieve what I wanted I only had to add:

```
  template: '<ui-view />',
```

Like so:

```
.state('foo', {
  abstract: true,
  url: "/foo",
  controller: 'FooCtrl',
  template: '<ui-view />',
})
```

A related discussion: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/325

Answer (score -2):

You're not specifying the url of #/foo/bar is all.

You are specifying the state of foo.bar, but the state is only being accessed from the url of #/bar.

Change the following...

```
  .state('foo.bar', {
    url: "/bar",
    controller: 'BarCtrl',
  })
```

... to ...

```
  .state('foo.bar', {
    url: "/foo/bar",
    controller: 'BarCtrl',
  })
```

... and you should be good.

Comment: No, with the dot notation the parent's url will automatically appended to the child's, see http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview